# Why are $K_{\alpha}$ and $K_{\beta}$ emissions denoted by $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, notation, x-rays

Perhaps this is a silly question, but is there any reason for the labelling of $K$ emissions as alpha and beta? From what I know, all $K$ emissions relate to an electron transition down to the $n=1$ energy state, and for atoms with relatively large atomic number, this would result in the emission of an X-ray photon, which we call the $K_{\alpha}$ and $K_{\beta}$; the former denoting a transition from $n=2$ $\rightarrow$ $n=1$ and the latter $n=3$ $\rightarrow$ $n=1$ (hence the latter releases a higher energy photon). Are these $\alpha$ and $\beta$ labels simply indicating their specific energy state transitions, or is there some link to $\alpha$ decay and $\beta$ decay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These labels have nothing to do with $\alpha$ decay and $\beta$ decay.
Instead, the labels indicate which electron transition is responsible for the x-rays.

Qouted from [Hyperphysics - Characteristic X-Rays](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/xrayc.html#c1):

> The x-rays produced by transitions from the $n=2$ to $n=1$ levels
> are called K-alpha x-rays,
> and those for the $n=3\to 1$ transition are called K-beta x-rays.